# This is about memory in Computers

Tags: memory-management, memory-address

Does a Bit have an address or
Does a Byte ( 8 bits ) have an address or
Does both have addresses..

If u don't understand wat an address is : it is a used to access data in memory
something like 0x0000

Comment: Just like the address on the outside of your building or house it is a concept of a way to uniquely identify a container.  it is not really practical to address individual bits, addresses generally are in units of bytes.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion on a similar subject: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91230/addressable-memory-unit

Comment: This question is way too broad, are you asking about a specific architecture? platform? language? Because yes, you can definitely change a single bit in the DRAM if you physically hack into the DDR chip and find the specific rank, bank, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Bits do not have an address, in the sense of being retrievable from the memory of a computer.

For convenience and historical reasons, data is addressed as bytes not bits. To work with an individual bit, in most programming languages you have to get the byte that contains the bit you want, and then perform some bit manipulation to convert it into a form that is usable by the language, like a byte or a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest adressable piece of memory is defined as byte. So an adress is used to define where the first of 8 bits is starting at. Did that help?

Comment: Answers are not for diatribes.  If you want to do that, use a comment.

Comment: You shouldn't ask counter questions in your answer in general.

Comment: Corrected it. Was really surprised about that kind of question. Perhaps only me?